# Why the name of the participant is not appearing?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a query in the getRegistrationInfo()  to get the details of a registration in a conference so is possible to show a list item for each participant associated with the registration.

For example if the user John register him and his collueague Jake in the conference "test conference", both in the registration type "general" I want to show two list items like:

```
Conference Name: test conference
Registration Type: general
Participant: Jake

Conference Name: test conference
Registration Type: general
Participant: John
```

Its working for the conference name and for the registration type name but for the participant name is not working, it appears "Trying to get property of non-object" with "`{{$registrationType->participants->participant->name}}`".

Do you know where is the issue?

getRegistrationInfo() method:

```
 public function getRegistrationInfo($regID)
    {
         $registration = Registration::with('conference.registrationTypes.participants')
        ->find($regID);

        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.registration', compact('registration'));
        return $pdf->download('info.pdf');
    }
```

Then in the view:

```
@foreach($registration->conference->registrationTypes as $registrationType)
    <li>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="conference-title">
                <strong>Conference</strong><br> <span>{{$registration->conference->name}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="conference-regtype">
                <div>
                    <strong>Registration Type </strong><br>
                    <span>{{$registrationType->name}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="conference-participant">
                <strong>Participant</strong><br>
                <span>{{$registrationType->participants->participant->name}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

The output of $registration in the method getRegistrationInfo():

```
Registration {#313 ▼
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "conference" => Conference {#318 ▼
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "registrationTypes" => Collection {#319 ▼
          #items: array:1 [▼
            0 => RegistrationType {#324 ▼
              #relations: array:1 [▼
                "participants" => Collection {#325 ▼
                  #items: array:2 [▼
                    0 => Participant {#331 ▼
                      #relations: []
                    }
                    1 => Participant {#333 ▼
                      #relations: []
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The output of $registrationType:

```
RegistrationType {#324 ▼
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "participants" => Collection {#325 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▼
        0 => Participant {#331 ▼
          #fillable: array:4 [▼
            0 => "name"
            1 => "surname"
            2 => "registration_id"
            3 => "registration_type_id"
          ]
        }
        1 => Participant {#333 ▼
          #fillable: array:4 [▼
            0 => "name"
            1 => "surname"
            2 => "registration_id"
            3 => "registration_type_id"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I mean, look at your error message. At some point in that line, you're trying to get a property out of a non-object. You never even show the definition of `$registrationType` that I can see, so I don't see how you expect us to be able to help.

Comment: Thanks, I update the question with the output of $registration.

Comment: What do you expect `->participants->participant->name` to do? Specifically, the `->participant` part? Did you mean to do an array access, because `->participants` is an array? There also doesn't seem to be a name anywhere. Please make a [mcve].

Comment: The participant has the name field, I update the question with the participant fields.

Comment: The participants still don't have a `name` field, they're an array with an element with the value `"name"`. Please actually take the time to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output should be as following:

```
  @foreach($registration->conference->registrationTypes as $registrationType)
    @foreach($registrationType->participants as $participant)
      <li>
          <div class="wrapper">
              <div class="conference-title">
                  <strong>Conference</strong><br> <span>{{ $registrationType->conference->name }}</span>
              </div>
              <div class="conference-regtype">
                  <div>
                      <strong>Registration Type </strong><br>
                      <span>{{ $registrationType->name }}</span>
                  </div>
              </div>  
              <div class="conference-participant">
                  <strong>Participant</strong><br>
                  <span>{{$participant->name}}</span>
              </div>
          </div>
      </li>
    @endforeach
  @endforeach
```

You may have to create or adjust relationships to the models involved in the operation.

Comment: Thanks, but like that the name of the fisrt participant apepars, but is only appearing one list item, the first participant, but it should appear two list items since there are two participants. Do you know what is the issue?

Comment: The output of `$registrationType` is displaying two `Participant` items in the collection, you must iterate it.

Comment: Thanks I have the foreach like "@foreach($registration->conference->registrationTypes as $registrationType)" because is also necessary to get info about the conferene name and registration type name. But I want to show only a participant name in each list item. Each list item should show the info about the participant name, conference name and registration type name and not show the conference name, registration type name and all participants name in the same list item.

Comment: `$participant` has what you are asking, `$participant->registrationType->name` and `$participant->registrationType->conference->name`.

Comment: Thanks, but it appears "Undefined variable: registrationType" in "@foreach($registrationType->participants as $participant)". With " public function getRegistrationInfo($regID)
    {
         $registration = Registration::with('conference.registrationTypes.participants')
        ->find($regID);

        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.registration', compact('registration'));
        return $pdf->download('info.pdf');
    }".